# How Docker selects an image's os/arch

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I started to learn how to work with Docker and I had this question.
When I make "docker pull <image-name>" I usually pull the image from docker hub.

But images can have different versions that differ in OS and architecture. For example a python image has versions with linux and windows.

[image: python image tags]

I'm wondering what image I'll get if I just do a "docker pull python" and how I can choose the OS and architecture myself.

I actually prefer to use linux images because it's lightweight and I don't want accidentally pull a windows image.

Comment: take a look at [this](https://hub.docker.com/_/python) scroll down and read about Image Variants. you can see `python:<version>-alpine` and also some description about it. please let me know if there was any problem.

Comment: @sajjadrezaei thanks for the reference, it pushed me to learn about shared and simple tags, so I understand the problem better now.

Comment: Also I checked some info about Windows and Linux containers, so I think that Docker chooses image's OS according to Docker mode (you can switch between Linux and Windows containers, so Docker fetch image's OS according to this), also answers to post make me understand how Docker determines image's architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm wondering what image I'll get if I just do a "docker pull python"

From "[Leverage multi-CPU architecture support](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/multi-arch/)"

> Most of the Docker Official Images on Docker Hub provide a variety of architectures.
> For example, the `busybox` image supports `amd64`, `arm32v5`, `arm32v6`, `arm32v7`, `arm64v8`, `i386`, `ppc64le`, and `s390x`.
> When running this image on an `x86_64` / `amd64` machine, the `amd64` variant is pulled and run.

So it depends on the OS used when you do your `docker pull`.

---

> and how I can choose the OS and architecture myself.

The same page adds:

> You can also run images targeted for a different architecture on Docker Desktop.
>
> You can run the images using the SHA tag, and verify the architecture.
> For example, when you run the following on a macOS:
>
> ```
> docker run --rm docker.io/username/demo:latest@sha256:2b77acdfea5dc5baa489ffab2a0b4a387666d1d526490e31845eb64e3e73ed20 uname -m
> ```
>
> aarch64
>
> ```
> docker run --rm docker.io/username/demo:latest@sha256:723c22f366ae44e419d12706453a544ae92711ae52f510e226f6467d8228d191 uname -m
> ```
>
> armv71
>
> In the above example, uname -m returns aarch64 and armv7l as expected, even when running the commands on a native macOS or Windows developer machine

Comment: To choose architecture yourself you can also use `--platform linux/amd64` flag in `docker run` command.

Answer (score 2):

It's based on the host platform where docker is running. You can see this in `docker info`:

```sh
$ docker info --format '{{ .OSType }}/{{ .Architecture }}'
linux/x86_64
```

The code for this is in [containerd](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/blob/140ecc9247386d3be21616fe285021c081f4ea08/platforms/platforms.go) and the OS and Arch are looked up slightly differently in go:

```sh
$ go env
GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="amd64"
...
GOOS="linux"
...
```